# Помогите подключить и отключить скрипты Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть 5 скриптов которые нужно отключить.
Вместо них подключить один минифицированный.
Подскажите как это сделать в Wordpress.
Пробовал по разному

```html
function modify_jquery() {
            if (!is_admin()) {           
// Убираем подключенную старую версию библиотеки
                wp_deregister_script('jquery');
            }
}
add_action('init', 'modify_jquery');
```

Тут получилось отключить jquerry
Но теперь хочу подключить вместо его другой скрипт

```html
function my_scripts_method(){
 wp_register_script('optimscript', '/grunt/js/optimjs.min.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_register_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

И этот второй код не работает. 
Если даже делаю так

```html
function my_scripts_method(){
 wp_enqueue_script('optimscript', '/grunt/js/optimjs.min.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Все равно не работает =((

Comment: wp_register_script не запускает скрипт, потому и не работает. А папка grunt у вас что, в корне сайта?

Comment: Да, уже кустарно подключил. 
Просто вставил в код <script></script>.
Но все равно как то странно. У меня там сжатая библиотека jquery. Я стандартную библиотеку jquery отключаю, зато подключаю свою сжатую через grunt.js. И итоге не работает ни  то ни другое.....

Comment: что-то делаете неправильно. Но без кода сказать сложно. Отключение и подключение скриптов - довольно рутинная операция. Делал на многих сайтах

Comment: Если конечно Вас не затруднит можете написать функцию которая отключает стиль который находится по такой ссылке ( названия не знаю ) 
https://мой-сайт/wp-content/plugins/content-views-query-and-display-post-page/public/assets/css/cv.css

Comment: Нет такой функции. Надо открыть исходный код плагина "Content views..." и посмотреть, как запускается cv.css. В wp_enqueue_style есть первый аргумент - $handle. Его и надо использовать для wp_dequeue_style

Comment: Где у вас лежит скрипт optimjs.min.js? Если в директории темы, то у вас явно не хватает get_template_directory_uri или get_stylesheet_directory_uri (если это дочерняя тема)

Comment: Я его могу положить где угодно. Подскажете, есть ли возможность указать адрес к скрипту в формате https://  ?
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
$handle - я так понимаю сам придумаю название и все? Или нужно его сначала зарегестрировать?
$src -  могу ли указать в формате https://
$deps, $ver, $media - могу ли я игнорировать это?